# How do I get a list of filenames at runtime, some with spaces, into an array?

Tags: bash, filenames, spaces, quoting

I need to get a list of filenames into an array have the user select one.

```
for i in $(ls -1 *.tgz*); do
  optstring="$optstring \"$i\""
done
options=($optstring)
```

This works, with or without quoting the input. But they are still split into spaces by the for loop.

Comment: `optstring` isn't an array. Also [Don't parse ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Just use a loop over a glob. Or better don't even bother looping. Just use `options=(*.tgz*)`. Also see [Bash FAQ 050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) for why you can't stick quotes into a string and make it work the way you want.

Comment: You are correct, o=(*.tgz*) works, didn't know bash did that one. Much easier than messing with IFS, or some other convoluted way. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`optstring` isn't an array it is, as the name suggests, a string. That's going to be a problem later. See [Bash FAQ 050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) for why you can't stick quotes into a string like that and make it work the way you want.

Also [Don't parse ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Just use a loop over a glob.

```
for i in *.tgz*; do ... done
```

Or even better than that don't even bother with a loop.

```
options=(*.tgz*)
printf '[%s]\n' "${options[@]}"
```